# Proper ways to test Webflux REST API

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, junit, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I'm building a REST service using Webflux and Reactive Mongo for the first time.

Here is my Controller and Service Implement:

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/endpoint/computer")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ComputerEndpoint {

    private final ComputerServiceImpl computerService;

    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public Mono<Computer> createNewComputer(@Valid @RequestBody Computer computer) {
        return computerService.create(computer);
    }

    @GetMapping
    public Flux<Computer> findAllComputer() {
        return computerService.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Mono<Computer> findOneComputer(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
        return computerService.findById(id);
    }

    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    public Mono<Computer> updateOneComputer(@PathVariable("id") String id, @Valid @RequestBody Computer parsedBody) {
        return computerService.update(id, parsedBody);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public Mono<Void> deleteOneComputer(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
        return computerService.deleteById(id);
    }

}
```

ServiceImpl:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ComputerServiceImpl implements ComputerService {

    private final ComputerRepository repo;

    @Override
    public Flux<Computer> findAll() {
        return repo.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Computer> findById(String id) {
        return repo.findById(id)
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new Exception("COMPUTER_NOT_FOUND")));
    }

    @Override
    public Flux<Computer> saveAll(List<Computer> computers) {
        return repo.saveAll(computers);
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Computer> create(Computer computer) {
        return repo.save(computer);
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Computer> update(String id, Computer computer) {
        return repo.findById(id)
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new Exception("COMPUTER_NOT_FOUND")))
                .map(c -> {
                    computer.setId(id);
                    return computer;
                })
                .flatMap(repo::save);
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> delete(Computer computer) {
        return repo.delete(computer);
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> deleteById(String id) {
        return repo.deleteById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> deleteAll() {
        return repo.deleteAll();
    }
}
```

And the principle of Reactive Stream (Mono and Flux) is pretty new to me. Then I'm trying to write some test for those methods using JUnit 5 and Mockito.

Test:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebFluxTest(controllers = ComputerEndpoint.class)
@Import(ComputerServiceImpl.class)
class ComputerEndpointTest {

    @MockBean
    ComputerServiceImpl service;

    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient client;

    @Test
    void createNewComputer() {

        Computer computer = new Computer();
        computer.setName("DESKTOP PC");
        computer.setComputerModel("OptiPlex 7020");
        computer.setComputerSpecs("Q87 Mainboard, i5-4590, 16Gb Ram, 1TB HDD, 256Gb SSD, 300W PSU");

        Mockito.when(service.create(computer)).thenReturn(Mono.just(computer));

        client.post()
                .uri("/endpoint/computer")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(computer))
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isCreated();

        Mockito.verify(service, Mockito.times(1)).create(computer);

    }

    @Test
    void findAllComputer() {

        Computer computer1 = new Computer();
        computer1.setName("DELL WORKSTATION");
        computer1.setComputerModel("OptiPlex 7020 Ultra");
        computer1.setComputerSpecs("Q87 Mainboard, i5-4590, 16Gb Ram, 1TB HDD, 256Gb SSD, 300W PSU");

        Computer computer2 = new Computer();
        computer2.setName("DELL PC");
        computer2.setComputerModel("OptiPlex 7020 Power");
        computer2.setComputerSpecs("Q87 Mainboard, i3-4150, 8Gb Ram, 500Gb HDD, 120Gb SSD, 300W PSU");

        Mockito.when(service.findAll()).thenReturn(Flux.just(computer1, computer2));

        client.get()
                .uri("/endpoint/computer")
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk()
                .expectBodyList(Computer.class);

        Mockito.verify(service, Mockito.times(1)).findAll();
    }

    @Test
    void findOneComputer() {

        Computer computer = new Computer();
        computer.setId("3b241101-e2bb-4255-8caf-4136c566a962");
        computer.setName("DESKTOP PC");
        computer.setComputerModel("OptiPlex 7020");
        computer.setComputerSpecs("Q87 Mainboard, i5-4590, 16Gb Ram, 1TB HDD, 256Gb SSD, 300W PSU");

        Mockito.when(service.findById(computer.getId())).thenReturn(Mono.just(computer));

        client.get()
                .uri("/endpoint/computer/{id}", computer.getId())
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk()
                .expectBody(Computer.class);

        Mockito.verify(service, Mockito.times(1)).findById(computer.getId());
    }

    @Test
    void updateOneComputer() {

        Computer computerOrigin = new Computer();
        computerOrigin.setId("3b241101-e2bb-4255-8caf-4136c566a962");
        computerOrigin.setName("DESKTOP PC");
        computerOrigin.setComputerModel("OptiPlex 7020");
        computerOrigin.setComputerSpecs("Q87 Mainboard, i5-4590, 16Gb Ram, 1TB HDD, 256Gb SSD, 300W PSU");

        Computer computerUpdated = new Computer();
        computerUpdated.setName("DELL PC");
        computerUpdated.setComputerModel("OptiPlex 7020 Power");
        computerUpdated.setComputerSpecs("Q87 Mainboard, i3-4150, 8Gb Ram, 500Gb HDD, 120Gb SSD, 300W PSU");

        Mockito.when(service.update(computerOrigin.getId(), computerUpdated))
                .thenReturn(Mono.just(computerOrigin));

        client.put()
                .uri("/endpoint/computer/{id}", computerOrigin.getId())
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(computerUpdated))
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk();

        Mockito.verify(service, Mockito.times(1)).update(computerOrigin.getId(), computerUpdated);

    }

    @Test
    void deleteOneComputer() {

        Computer computer = new Computer();
        computer.setId("3b241101-e2bb-4255-8caf-4136c566a962");
        computer.setName("DESKTOP PC");
        computer.setComputerModel("OptiPlex 7020");
        computer.setComputerSpecs("Q87 Mainboard, i5-4590, 16Gb Ram, 1TB HDD, 256Gb SSD, 300W PSU");

        Mockito.when(service.deleteById(computer.getId())).thenReturn(Mono.empty());
        System.out.println(service.findById(computer.getId()));

        client.delete()
                .uri("/endpoint/computer/{id}", computer.getId())
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk();


        Mockito.verify(service, Mockito.times(1)).deleteById(computer.getId());

    }
}
```

All tests are passed. But I'm not sure the mocking processes has been done right, and the expectation are met without any persist in Mocks. Especially with delete test when I doubted about the mock of delete its Id without persist it.

So the question is, which is the proper way to writing reactive services test and how to set expectation meet everything to really pass the test?

I might be confusing atm, but please kindly help.

Comment: I just glanced over it and the first that struck me was the use of `Exception` generic exceptions are not good practice because as it tends to be very generic and hard to identify problems. Returning a `ResponseStatusException` would be a bit more appropriate here https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-exception-handler

Comment: I think your stuff is good for an unit test. but you can do another integration test with embeded mongodb (end to end).

Comment: @TinyOS thanks. i just found some point to taking to the unit test, and the intergration test is a good idea.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf thank you. I will try to look for some proper way to throw exception.

Answer (score 0):

This looks good. Just keep in mind that you're really testing your url -> controller mapping, controller -> service mapping, url security, http verb, payload annotations, etc.

You'll likely want to write separate integration tests for the actual service implementation.